# Not able to write/delete file in latest OSX 10.13.4

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have written the code to just update the file or delete a file but not able to do any operation through code but can do manually.

This is the error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“extensions 2.json” couldn’t
>   be removed because you don’t have permission to access it."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/UserName/Desktop/extensions 2.json,
>   NSUserStringVariant=( Remove ), NSUnderlyingError=0x6040004598f0
>   {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

Comment: This is the error.

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“extensions 2.json” couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/UserName/Desktop/extensions 2.json, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSUnderlyingError=0x6040004598f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

Comment: Can you also share your code?

Answer (score 0):

There was something related to sandbox issue. Sandbox was enable in new Xcode 9 by default which was not allowing me to delete the selected file.

But now my requirement slightly changed. Can I delete some files through a program without admin passwords prompt ?